# How to send data (through JSON) for javascript development (for old webform project with xsd DataSet)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, xsd, dataset

Here's my situation:

I have an existing ASP.NET webforms solution that is production-ready. We are changing this solution in multiple ways.

One of the changes is to have the existing solution do less HTML and stylesheet work from code behind (based on user data in the database), but to push that raw(er) data to the page so that my fresh team of javascript developers can create a cool interactive layer.

Due to other project requirements, the code has already been updated to ASP.NET 4.5, but is still using an XSD for our db interaction. My javascript team has asked that the back-end expose data through JSON.

Now I am reading up - as I have not coded since 2011 - on new(er) technologies (WebApi, serialization / deserialization, webmethod etc.) but in the meantime, the javascript team is waiting.

So my question to you: what is the best way in codebehind to expose my data for javascript to use, using the xsd (or straight db calls if the xsd is in fact a drawback)? Short sample code would be appreciated.